# Beneath the Waves

Tags: pattern, english, language, word-sequence

What is unique/unusual about the following strange couplet?

> a serene summer moon waxes over a wave-worn azure sea.
>
> an orca moans an arcane verse as mermen caress a venomous sea anemone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> All the letters are "short" lowercase letters and don't extend below the line. E.g. no l's, t's, k's, g's, etc.

Comment: Indeed, indeed.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @Ben said,

> None of them drop below the line, no "p", no "q"

Comment: Yeah I must have been in the middle of editing mine when you posted yours. Also it's good to see a fellow Coloradan on here!

Comment: Huzzah for CO! Not much longer for me though.

Comment: Sad to see you go :(

Answer (score 0):

Also,
a serene summer moon waxes over a wave-worn azure sea.

> Three words each begin with the letters "a", "s", and "w" with an "o" as the only solo

an orca moans an arcane verse as mermen caress a venomous sea anemone.

> a 6, v 2, m 2, s 1, o 1 The sum of the number of words that do not start with "a" equals the total number of words that start with "a"

Comment: Downvoted just because it's the wrong answer?